# How to copy text from a given line and column number and paste it in another file at a given line and column number

Tags: bash

I have a file address.txt containing
`0x0003FFB0'
at line 1 and column 2
i want to paste it in another file 'linker.txt' at line 20 and column 58
How can i do that using bash scripting?
Note that the content of the input file can be random , doesn't have to be same each time.
But the length of the word to be copied will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use SED

```
sed -i.old '20s/^.{58}/&0x0003FFB0/' file
```

it will produce a file.old with the original content and file will be updated with this address. Quickly explain

```
sed '20command'    file  # do command in line 20
sed '20s/RE/&xxx/' file  # search for regular expression, replace by the original text (&) + xxx
```

to read the address and put in this sed, cut it possible

```
ADDRESS=$(head -1 address.txt | cut -f2)
sed -i.old "20s/^.{58}/&${ADDRESS}/" file
```

Comment: `ADDRESS=$(head -1 address.txt | cut -f2)`   `sed -i.old "20s/^.{58}/&${ADDRESS}/" file`   how will this code change if the input text be at line 2 and column 2  @Tiago Peczenyj

Comment: Perhaps you have a different version of `sed`.  Try with `sed -r` and/or change the `.{58}` to `..........................................................` literally.

Comment: sorry. use sed '20s/.\{58\}/ -- i forget this detail in sed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of head and tail to get any line number. To get line 2, get the last line (using tail) of the first two lines (using head):

```
ADDRESS=$(head -2 address.txt | tail -1 | cut -f2)
```

For the third line:

```
ADDRESS=$(head -3 address.txt | tail -1 | cut -f2)
```

And so on.